# How to run code when a variable changes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to coding and I am trying to figure out how to make my code run when the variable i increases.

The current code executes when i = 1, as defined (.q1). The code also increases the variable i to 2, however, on the next click for .q2, the code doesn't run and I'm not sure why.

Can anyone help explain why the code doesn't run on the next set of buttons (i=2)?

```js
var score = 0
var i = 1

$('.q' + i).on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is("#correct"))
    $(this).addClass("theright") && ++score;
  else {
    $(this).addClass("thewrong");
  }
  $('.q' + i).attr('disabled', 'disabled') && ++i;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q1 id=correct type="button">option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class=q1 type="button">option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q1 type="button">option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class=q1 type="button">option 4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q2 type="button">option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class=q2 type="button">option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q2 id=correct type="button">option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class=q2 type="button">option 4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- The main issue is that `$('.q' + i).on` is only evaluated once, when `i` is still zero. Although the click handler increases `i`, this has no effect on anything.
- In valid HTML you cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute value, so make "correct" a CSS class instead of an ID.
- It is bad practice to suffix CSS class names (or id attributes) with a sequential number (like `q1`, `q2`). Instead, use one class `q` and the fact that answers to the same question are grouped in the same `table` element. You can find the `table` to which the clicked button belongs, and then find the `q` elements inside of it.
- You can then also use *one* click handler. No more fiddling with `+ i` to create the desired selector.

Here is your corrected snippet:

```js
var score = 0

$('.q').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(".correct")) {
    $(this).addClass("theright") && ++score;
    $("#score").text(score);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("thewrong");
  }
  $(this).closest("table").find(".q").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

```css
.theright { background: green }
.thewrong { background: red }
table { margin: 10px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q correct" type="button">option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class="q" type="button">option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q" type="button">option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class="q" type="button">option 4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q" type="button">option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class="q" type="button">option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q correct" type="button">option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class="q" type="button">option 4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

Score: <span id="score">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the new click handler for i+1 inside your existing click handler.

```
var score = 0
var i = 1
        
function registerClick() {
  $('.q'+i).on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).is("#correct"))
      $(this).addClass("theright") && ++score;
    else {
      $(this).addClass("thewrong");
    }
    $('.q'+i).attr('disabled', 'disabled') && ++i;
    // register new click handler for ++i
    registerClick(i);
  })
}
    
registerClick();
```

The problem is that your code only **once** assign a clickHandler for i = 1. So you need to register a new handler every time i is going to change.